# Apache Cayenne Get Collection Expression

Tags: expression, apache-cayenne

Using [Apache Cayenne](http://cayenne.apache.org/) I am trying to figure out how to avoid doing iterative calls to the DB when I have a Collection of attribute values.

Say we have a persistent object `Person` with an attribute `name` of type **String**. If I have a List containing names of the `Person` I would like to generate an expression that allows a **single** DB call rather than iterating over the list and getting each `Person` in turn.

This doesn't actually exist but I would like something like this:

```
List<String> names = ...;
ExpressionFactory.orLikeExp(Person.NAME_PROPERTY, names);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ExpressionFactory.join(..):

```
List<Expression> pairs = new ArrayList<>(names.size());
for(String name : names) {
    // use an expression appropriate for comparison... 
    // "like" in this example, but can be "equals", etc.
    pairs.add(ExpressionFactory.likeExp(Person.NAME_PROPERTY, name));
}

Expression e = ExpressionFactory.joinExp(Expression.OR, pairs);
```